# Python: Time/Frames Conversion Calculator

Tags: python, animation, pyqt5, calculator

This is a very beginner question but I have really tried and failed.

I am trying to make a simple animation time calculator to help me with work.
I want it to have 3 user inputs:

**1) Frames Per Second
2) Total Frames
3) Total Time**

Something like:
**total_frames = seconds * framerate
total_time = frames / framerate**

The problems I'm having are:

1. How do I link the result of the variables to the user input on the gui ? And then have, for example, **total_frames** to update when the user has input **framerate** and **total_time**, but also have **total_time** update when the user has input **framerate** and **total_frames** .
2. How to get the total time to get the format **mm/ss/ff** ( with ff being frames based on **framerate** ).
   So like a normal minutes and seconds timer but instead of milliseconds you have the **framerate** as max per second.

I have managed to get the basic code working just printing out the results of the variables.
And I have also managed to make a basic gui that takes input from the user with Qt designer.

I hope I have explained that decently. Any help will be much appreciated. I'm a total noob but trying to get there slowly.

**attempt 1:**

my code:

```
    from datetime import time
from calc import *

framerate = 24#input('Frames Per Second ?')
seconds = 10 #input('How Many Seconds ?')

frames = seconds * framerate
total_time = frames / framerate

print(frames)
print(total_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    AnimationCalculator = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_AnimationCalculator()
    ui.setupUi(AnimationCalculator)
    AnimationCalculator.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

my gui:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_AnimationCalculator(object):
    def setupUi(self, AnimationCalculator):
        AnimationCalculator.setObjectName("AnimationCalculator")
        AnimationCalculator.resize(341, 224)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(105, 173, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(105, 173, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(105, 173, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(105, 173, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(105, 173, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(105, 173, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        AnimationCalculator.setPalette(palette)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AnimationCalculator)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 80, 161, 61))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        self.label.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Myriad Pro")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhDigitsOnly|QtCore.Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 150, 161, 61))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        self.label_2.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Myriad Pro")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhDigitsOnly|QtCore.Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 10, 161, 61))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        self.label_3.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Myriad Pro")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.timeEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.timeEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 191, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.timeEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.timeEdit_2.setObjectName("timeEdit_2")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 81, 191, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhDigitsOnly)
        self.spinBox.setWrapping(False)
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setReadOnly(False)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.PlusMinus)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(50000)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(1)
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.spinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 191, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.spinBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox_2.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhDigitsOnly)
        self.spinBox_2.setWrapping(False)
        self.spinBox_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox_2.setReadOnly(False)
        self.spinBox_2.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.PlusMinus)
        self.spinBox_2.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox_2.setMaximum(240)
        self.spinBox_2.setSingleStep(1)
        self.spinBox_2.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.spinBox_2.setObjectName("spinBox_2")
        AnimationCalculator.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(AnimationCalculator)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AnimationCalculator)

    def retranslateUi(self, AnimationCalculator):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AnimationCalculator.setWindowTitle(_translate("AnimationCalculator", "Animation Calculator"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("AnimationCalculator", "Frames"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("AnimationCalculator", "Time"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("AnimationCalculator", "FPS"))
        self.timeEdit_2.setDisplayFormat(_translate("AnimationCalculator", "HH:mm:ss"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    AnimationCalculator = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_AnimationCalculator()
    ui.setupUi(AnimationCalculator)
    AnimationCalculator.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit

framerate = 24#input('Frames Per Second ?')
seconds = 5  #input('How Many Seconds ?')

total_frames = seconds * framerate
total_time = total_frames / framerate


def onChangeFPS():
    fps = field_1.text()
    print(fps)

def onChangeFrames():
    framerate = field_2.text()
    print(total_frames)

def onChangeSeconds():
    total_seconds = field_3.text()

    print(total_time)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget_1 = QWidget()

field_1 = QLineEdit(widget_1)
field_1.move(1 , 20)
field_1.resize(200 , 30)
field_1.returnPressed.connect(onChangeFPS)

field_2 = QLineEdit(widget_1)
field_2.move(1 , 50)
field_2.resize(200 , 30)
field_2.returnPressed.connect(onChangeFrames)

field_3 = QLineEdit(widget_1)
field_3.move(1 , 80)
field_3.resize(200 , 30)
field_3.returnPressed.connect(onChangeSeconds)

widget_1.setGeometry(100,100,300,150)
widget_1.setWindowTitle("Animation Time Calculator")
widget_1.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sorry for the wall of code and thanks again !

**UPDATE 2021-09-19:** Ok, so I have tried a lot of things and I realised having the script work in a way that chooses the flow of code based on the initial input ( ie: it knows to calculate time if the user put in frames first, or vice versa) is way to hard for me to underdstand with the procedural flow of the code.

So I decided to try break it up into a couple definitions and ask the user which version they would like to use.

I have managed to get it working, it's just getting the miliseconds to be determined by the user input for framerate, and displaying the result in a mm:ss:frames format that I don't understand.

Once I figure that out I'm going to get the gui going and will update that here when I do.

Here's my updated code:

```
def framecount():

    fps = int(input("Enter Frames per Second: "))
    total_time = float(input("Enter total time: "))
    total_frame = fps * total_time
    print("Total frames: {}".format(total_frame))

def timecount():

    fps = int(input("Enter Frames per Second: "))
    total_frame = int(input("Enter total frame: "))
    total_time = total_frame / fps
    print("Total time: {}".format(total_time)+" seconds")

choose = int(input("What would you like to calculate ? 1. Total Frames 2. Total Time : "))


if choose == 1:
    framecount()

elif choose == 2:
    timecount()
```

**UPDATE 2 2021-09-19:**

It seems that **datetime.timedelta()** can do what I want with the format for **total_time**

This is the code, the only thing I really can't work out is how to get **milliseconds to reset to zero** every time it goes +1 over the user input for **fps**

This is my code:

```
from datetime import timedelta


def framecount():

    fps = int(input("Enter Frames per Second: "))
    total_time = float(input("Enter total time: "))
    total_frame = fps * total_time
    print("Total frames: {}".format(total_frame))

def timecount():

    fps = int(input("Enter Frames per Second: "))
    total_frame = int(input("Enter total frame: "))


    total_time = timedelta( seconds=(total_frame / fps), milliseconds=total_frame )
    print("Total time: {}".format(total_time))

choose = int(input("What would you like to calculate ? 1. Total Frames 2. Total Time : "))


if choose == 1:
    framecount()

elif choose == 2:
    timecount()

else:
    print("Please choose option 1. or 2.)")
```

with my test inputs this prints out:

> What would you like to calculate ? 1. Total Frames 2. Total Time :
> **2** Enter Frames per Second: **25** Enter total frame: **107** Total time: **0:00:04.387000**

Comment: Please consider adding `[pyqt]` or `[pyqt5]` tag to your question so it would be easier to spot for users having experience with this tool

Comment: For the second part of your question what happens if the total minutes is more than 60? For example if the total minutes are 420 mins and 69 secs with fps 120 do you want the string to be like “420/69/120”?

Comment: @Daweo : Tag is added :)

Comment: @t.abraham : The idea would be, if the frame counter goes over the user input for Frames Per Second, it becomes zero and adds 1 to seconds. if minutes becomes 60, it should go to zero and add 1 to hours. so if I set Frames Per Second to 24- 9 seconds and 23 frames would display as - 00:00:09:23 but adding one more frame would change it to- 9 seconds and 24 frames would display as - 00:00:10:00

Comment: @GDonkey Okey got it. this means u will need a total of 6 different variables (beginner version) 3 variables keep the user input values and the rest 6 are the ones coming from the animation. Could you please share the updated version of the code based on the code I posted in the answers, so that I can get at what point and how the actual fps, time, frames are retrived?

Comment: @t-abraham Sadly I can't seem to grasp how to do something like this. I did try. 

I switched off all the gui stuff just to simplify things. 
Where I get stuck, is there is always one priority and order to ask the questions in a procedural flow like this. But I want a kind of switching back and forth depending which input ( between total_frames and total_time ) the user decides to input. 

I guess it's a 2 in 1 calculator. so if i chose to input total time first. total frames should update automatically and vice versa. but how do you get it to swap the priority like that ?

Comment: @t-abraham i would add the code but it's basically what you gave me and i keep trying to adjust and shuffle values around. just trying to get a working print out and understand what i'm doing better then try to connect to an actual gui.

Comment: @t-abraham Sorry that took a while, but I have updated a couple times onto my original post to show my progress so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
fps = int(input("Enter Frames per Second: ") or None)
total_time = int(input("Enter total time: ") or None)
total_frame = int(input("Enter total frame: ") or None)


if not fps is None and not total_time is None:
         total_frame = fps * total_time
elif not fps is None and not total_frame is None:
         total_time = total_frame / fps
else:
     # here you can enter default time, fps
```

You can use this part at the top of your code to get the user inputs and then process the 3rd variable accordingly to the inputs. Here the priority gets fps and total time first…

This is the easiest version but if you want more sophisticated ones those can be done too… let me know

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ! 
I much prefer the "easy version" like this so I can understand what's actually happening. 
I am going to play around with this and report back.